# Creating a scalar product function

Tags: vector, products

I'm new to *Mathematica* and I'm struggling a bit with it. I need to make a function that returns me the scalar product $a\cdot b$ of two vectors $a$ and $b$, without using the `.` (`Dot`) function.

Can someone give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: `Inner` will do.

Comment: Is this homework?  Hints: `Total` & `Times` or `Inner` or `Sum`, countless ways.

Comment: ``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`DOT[a, b]``  ;-)